# Given $f'(x)\leq 1-f(x)^2$, prove $|f(x)|\leq 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $f$ be $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $$f'(x)\leq
>  1-f(x)^2$$ Prove that $|f(x)|\leq 1 \: \forall x$.

I suppose that such a function can be bounded by a solution to the ODE: $y'=1-y^2$
with the same initial value, but I don't know by which theorem, if at all.

Trying to solve this ODE gives:
$$\frac{dy}{1-y^2}=dx \Rightarrow \int\frac{dy}{1-y^2}=\int dx=x+c$$
but now another problem arises: $\frac{1}{y^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y+1} \right )$
 and so taking anti-derviative depends whether $|y|\leq 1$ or not, which makes me even more confused.

Can someone please make me some sense of all this mess?

Comment: Not a "mess" at all, rather a cute little exercise to check that one really understands the behaviour of solutions of autonomous differential equations. Assume for instance that $f(x_0)<-1$. Then the idea is that $f'(x)$ is "too large" for $x>x_0$, so that the solution explodes in finite time, that is, there exists some finite $x_1>x_0$ such that $f(x)\to-\infty$ when $x\to x_1^-$, contradicting the hypothesis that $f$ is defined on the whole real line. Likewise, if $f(x_0)>1$, there exists some finite $x_1<x_0$ such that $f(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to x_1^+$. Any idea to show these?

Comment: @Did Absolutely not, sorry. If you could write down a solution I should be able to solve the other similar questions, I guess I'm missing the method for questions like these in general. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to prove that
$$|f(0)|=:c>1\tag{1}$$
is impossible.

If $(1)$ holds with $f(0)=c$ define $g(x):=f(-x)$, and if $(1)$ holds with$f(0)=-c$ define $g(x):=-f(x)$. In both cases we obtain
$$g(0)=c>1,\qquad g'(x)\geq g^2(x)-1\quad(x\geq0)\ .$$
It is then obvious that $g$ increases on ${\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$; hence $g(x)>1$ for all $x\geq0$. Now
$$g'\geq g^2-1=(g-1)^2+2(g-1)> (g-1)^2$$
implies
$${g'(t)\over \bigl(g(t)-1\bigr)^2}>1\qquad(t\geq0)\ .$$ We integrate this from $t=0$ to $t=x>0$ and obtain
$$-{1\over g(t)-1}\biggr|_0^x> x\ ,$$
and this expands to
$$g(x)>1+{1\over C-x}\quad (0<x<C)\ ,$$
where we have put ${1\over c-1}=:C$. This shows that $g$, hence $f$, cannot live over all of ${\mathbb R}$.